# Cannot create Matrix, even though I followed most tips, it keeps coming up as data frame

Tags: r, matrix

Im fairly new to R, and mostly using R Studio.

I have a table, converted it to a .txt file and used

`data<-read.table("file.txt, header=TRUE,fill=TRUE,sep="\t")`

It worked but it still comes up as data.frame. I need it to be as a Matrix so I can work with it properly (this according to my thesis supervisor.) I tried `as.matrix` but that just printed me nonsense

Example:

```
F20 10,16   289,09  583,20  2,51    437,11  13,98   19,71   188,71  18,42   73,01   710,31  865,29  17,76   17,76   1,92    647,38  39,36   3,81    10,78
F20 10,93   90,19   70,80   0,00    649,25  8,82    42,14   91,92   20,66   171,15  815,71  160,15  12,64   12,64   0,00    767,26  69,59   0,84    7,59
F20 12,74   69,46   73,37   0,26    694,33  11,72   105,12  137,38  80,39   131,97  965,46  142,83  32,25   32,25   0,00    894,98  216,50  2,86    25,48
F20 3,20    69,03   171,26  0,89    559,21  17,33   41,10   151,85  46,12   34,33   761,29  240,60  10,89   10,89   0,00    734,26  89,29   1,18    7,65
F20 4,82    86,64   85,95   0,69    188,36  5,51    17,18   55,00   13,06   205,56  280,50  171,91  4,82    4,82    0,00    253,69  32,32   0,69    2,76
F20 15,82   284,87  295,92  2,73    585,65  13,11   53,70   73,66   28,91   197,50  735,63  581,49  15,82   15,82   0,00    682,66  84,65   4,13    8,94
F20 6,35    113,53  22,18   1,58    265,69  2,66    17,96   63,37   27,46   583,19  358,69  136,24  3,69    3,69    0,00    340,72  49,64   1,06    2,11
```

Comment: Have in mind that matrices can not hold different data types. They must be all the same (all numeric or all character, etc...). Also, you say *I tried as.matrix but that just printed me nonsense*...can you show us?

Comment: Please provide couple of lines from "file.txt".

Comment: Hey, thanks, its all numbers. after checking it I noticed one later attached, removed it and tried as.matrix again. It came back fine but now when I Try to perform tests, it won't work. Specifics: Wilcox.test(X~Group, paired=FALSE) and it gives me cannot find X

Comment: Just copied a little example of file.txt in my questions. Its 111 observations of 20 variables. It has column headers, but I can't copy those since its a medical thesis and I Cant provide sensitive information

Answer (score 0):

We need to set the decimal character:

```
myData <- read.table("file.txt", dec = ",")
```

Then drop 1st column, as it is not numeric, and convert to matrix:

```
myDataMatrix <- as.matrix(myData[, -1])
```

---

**Edit:**
To keep 1st columns as Case Control status as OP indicated we could:

```
#add rownames as IDs
row.names(myDataMatrix) <- myData$V1
```

Or

```
#add Case Control status as new column
myDataMatrix <- cbind(myDataMatrix,
                      caco = as.numeric(myData$V1 == "F20"))
```

Comment: Thank You!! one more follow up question: by doing that it got rid of my first column which actually had the two group names, I guess since those weren't numbers, they have been deleted? There was a control and a case group. Also R still can't find the objects from the Matrix. I know attach(file) doesn't work with Matrix, so how do do that?

Comment: @Rebecca I suspect that by "matrix" your supervisor means a _model matrix_ which would include the information in your group column. You should confirm with him what he means

Comment: @HongOoi possible. He just said that I might have a problem with the difference between data frame and Matrix in R, so I assumed that the problem lay here. thank you all for your help

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Problem remains: I now have dataMatrix displayed in R studio but cannot use it as it returns "object not found". When working with data frames the command attach would get rid of that, but with the Matrix I can't use it..

Comment: @Rebecca One question at a time, please. You had an issue with reading the file into R as matrix, which is now solved with this answer. Start a new question for further questions.